# Org-Mode with Scimax changing #+LATEX_CLASS

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I installed [scimax](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax) on both linux and mac osx. And I am having the same issue for both.  I start the emacs by executing the ./scimax script then I open example/cmu-qualifier.org file and try to export it by pressing `C-c C-e j o`. Finally, I expect to see an article with columns like in a scientific paper but what I see is a common export of org-mode to pdf.

Should I change the `#+LATEX_CLASS: article` to something else ?

B.R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMU qualifer does not look like an article with columns. It is a regular article class, with some customization for what the qualifier reports in chemical engineering at CMU are supposed to look like.

Comment: Great tool by the way.